# C / Linux - How to connect and read the answer of a mail server like gmail or outlook with sockets?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, imap, pop3

I would like to connect to a mail server to read the mail. For example, I have an outlook address toto@outlook.com, and I want to get all the mail of this mailbox and be able to read it. So I believe I only have to do a client, but : How do I contact and connect to this type of servers, and how do I listen the answer?

Here is my current client code :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int     main()
{
  struct protoent       *pe;
  int                   fd_client;
  struct sockaddr_in    s_in;
  int                   port;
  char                  *ip;
  char                  buff[4096];

  ip = strdup("157.56.242.251"); // I get it while calling "ping outlook.com"
  port = 210;
  pe = getprotobyname("TCP");
  fd_client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, pe->p_proto);
  s_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
  s_in.sin_port = htons(port);
  s_in.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
  if (connect(fd_client, (struct sockaddr *)&s_in, sizeof(s_in)) == -1)
    {
      if (close(fd_client) == -1)
        return (-1);
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect\n");
      return (-1);
    }

   //From here I don't know what to do, so I tried this
   recv(fd_client, buff, 4096, 0);
   printf("%s\n",buff);
   write(fd_client, "Hello !\n", strlen("Hello !\n"));
   //To Here

  if (close(fd_client) == -1)
    return (-1);
  return (0);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which protocol do you want to use?

Comment: I suggest using some existing SMTP or POP or IMAP client library for this.

Comment: I want to use POP3 and Imap.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That would be nice =) But I have to do that for a project and I can't use any library except the standard libraries.

Comment: Well, then this is not really a question of programming, but of how IMAP and POP3 work. If you want to go the hard way, read the corresponding rfc's!

Comment: @Sascha I'm reading things since the morning. And I don't know which system call to use to do that.

Comment: http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ will teach you which syscalls to use. And you also could `strace` some existing mailing client program to understand what it is doing.

Comment: Okay, maybe I didn't get you right: Do you need help using sockets or help how to "speak" POP3/IMAP?

Comment: Then, pick some really basic C-socket-Tutorial ... anything that compiles. Maybe an Echo-Server or whatever. That wll get you startet. There isn't much more that you would need, since you could do POP3 using telnet... which I would suggest you to do next. To get a basical feeling.

Comment: @Sascha I already did that, I succeed to send a message to a remote computer with a small server. But I don't know how to contact a mailbox server to get informations from it using sockets like in the example code.

Comment: You make a connection to the correct mailserver address on the correct port. That's it. There is nothing special about connecting to a mailserver instead of an http server or anything else. You just make a TCP connection. It's up to you to find the exact address and port. You should find that in the help of your mail-providers website. Once you have a connection, it's all about how POP3/IMAP works.

Comment: @Sascha Ok, I'll loof for it. Then how do I recieve the answers of the server? Which system call and how to handle it?

Comment: @Sascha Ok, I just found the addresse and the port of outlook =)

Comment: Usually you read and write using the same socket, since they are full duplex (not like a lot of pipes). It is very similair to reading or writing a file. This is something every basic socket tutorial will show you without any fancy overhead.

Comment: Don't forget to use `errno`, perhaps thru `strerror(errno)` or `perror` (to display the cause of any failed syscall). Of course, test every syscall - they may fail......

Comment: @Sascha Do you have one? Because I found some, but that was not that useful. And so for the sockets I just have to read and write on it?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I do handle the errors, I just removed some here, so that the code is cleaner.

Comment: Don't have an idea :-) I remember there was a series of 10 or 12 videos... something like "Socket programming 101" or so... that way very detailed.

Comment: Trying to write a pop/imap client from scratch is insanity. If you want to know how the POP/IMAP protocols work, then you need to read the RFCs that define them

Comment: Insanity by EPITECH! And we have to rush the project in one weekend :p https://www.epitech.eu/intra/projet/3030//bmail_en.pdf